# How to handle button click when keyboard is open?

Tags: android, cordova

I am building a Cordova Android app. It is a webview application. I have a button on the UI and I attached `onClick` function. It works fine. But if the keyboard is open. Clicking the button will dismiss the keyboard but don't trigger the button click event. I have to tap the button twice. Is there a way to click the button make the keyboard dismiss and also trigger the button click event?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem where clicking a button in Cordova first closed the keyboard and then required a subsequent click to trigger the event. I resolved the issue by implementing the Cordova Fastclick plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-fastclick